# Docs Inserted Image always before all text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Making a simple app script that puts images and Text into a Google Doc separated by 2 Columns, for whatever reason, no matter the way I try it the images are always above the text (Inline) in the Doc, even though they should be layered (Inline),

```
 //Replace QR Code
  
  let qrText = editLocalBody.findText("{{qrCode}}");
  let setImagePlace = qrText.getElement().asText().replaceText("{{qrCode}}", "");
  let qrCodeImage = setImagePlace.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, qrCodeBlob);
```

From what I've seen this should insert an image wherever the text was previously located, but when it runs this it's always in the wrong spot, somehow above the text it was suppost to be in!

//Edit - To Show The Progression Of What Is Suppose To Happen And What Actually Happens:

I'm making QR Code badges for a propriety system that runs integrated tightly with Google, so I'm using appscript to get an entry from a google form containing an amount of badges (With relevent data) and autofill a Google Doc Accordingly.

// Loop Start

I fill my template with a text line that has key words in it I can select and replace later, with a keyword it can use to insert another this (This Part Works)

I first edit (findText("{{qrCode}}");) the QR Code, replacing (.replaceText) the keyword for it to nothing ("")

I then get the parent of the piece of code I ran above, which is a block of text ***(I think all the text in the Doc, I think this is where the issue lies, it puts it above the text because it's just one 'paragraph' or not multiple 'bodies' of text, if I could separate this I think it would work!)*** As a paragraph, and insert An Inline Image at Child Index (0, of the image ,qrCodeBlob)

I've debugged this script quite a bit, so I know It's that final line that inserting images fails, it sees all the text as 'one'.

// I want this (In Descending Order, each it's own full line):
Image
Text
Image
Text

//What It Gives Me (In Descending Order, each it's own full line):
Image
Image
Text
Text

```
 let qrCodeImage = setImagePlace.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, qrCodeBlob);
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: Certainly, I'll edit the main question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I can include pictures if that helps, but the most recent edit gives an idea I hope

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although unfortunately, from your updated question, I cannot still understand your question, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: I've compiled a short Powerpoint with pictures, does this help explain in detail: https://temp.sh/JCnyp/Expl.pptx